# Naming complex sub-select "as" in case statement

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to prevent the results of a complex sub-select, which is being used as part of a larger INSERT statement, from being NULL.  The value of the field must be an empty string instead of NULL.

Overall, the insert looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO record (id,field1,field2) VALUES (val1,val2,<complex select>);
```

To prevent the complex select from being NULL I can use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <complex select> THEN <complex select> else '' end as b
```

The problem is, I don't want to repeat the complex select as it makes the query twice as big, hard to read, prone to error if the query must be changed slightly, etc., so I would like to name the result of the select so I can just refer to the value instead. But when I try to do this I get an error:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <complex select> as a THEN a else '' end as b
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (<complex select> as a) THEN a else '' end as b
```

The error is:

```
near "as": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a column of a complex select a name, but to get a value out of a subquery, you must use another SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO record (id,field1,field2)
VALUES (val1,
        val2,
        (SELECT CASE WHEN a THEN a else '' END
         FROM (SELECT ... AS a FROM ...)
       );
```

(The subquery itself could be given a name, but it does not matter here.)

However, to convert a NULL value into an empty string, you can just use the [IFNULL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
INSERT INTO record (id,field1,field2)
VALUES (val1,
        val2,
        IFNULL((SELECT ...), '')
       );
```